# Fixed Point (Value equal to index) in a given array - 1 indexed using binary search

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search, binary-search

Is it possible to modify this code so that the index value starts from 1, instead of 0?
So, if the array is 0 1 3 4, the program will return 3.

```
class Main 
    { 
        static int binarySearch(int arr[], int low, int high) 
        { 
            if(high >= low) 
            {    
                /* low + (high - low)/2; */
                int mid = (low + high)/2;   
                if(mid == arr[mid]) 
                    return mid; 
                if(mid > arr[mid]) 
                    return binarySearch(arr, (mid + 1), high); 
                else
                    return binarySearch(arr, low, (mid -1)); 
            } 
            
            /* Return -1 if there is  
               no Fixed Point */
            return -1; 
        } 
            
        //main function 
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        { 
            int arr[] = {-10, -1, 0, 3 , 10, 11, 30, 50, 100}; 
            int n = arr.length; 
            System.out.println("Fixed Point is " 
                       + binarySearch(arr,0, n-1));         
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

just change the `0` to `1` and `n-1` to `n` when calling `binarySearch` and add a random number at 0 index of arr, i.e. do as follows:

```
int arr[] = {99999999/*note this random large number*/, -10, -1, 0, 4/*note this 4*/ , 10, 11, 30, 50, 100};
```

and

```
binarySearch(arr, 1, n);
```

A full example with proof:

```
public class SOTest 
    { 
        static int binarySearch(int arr[], int low, int high) 
        { 
            if(high >= low) 
            {    
                /* low + (high - low)/2; */
                int mid = (low + high)/2;   
                if(mid == arr[mid]) 
                    return mid; 
                if(mid > arr[mid]) 
                    return binarySearch(arr, (mid + 1), high); 
                else
                    return binarySearch(arr, low, (mid -1)); 
            } 
            
            /* Return -1 if there is  
               no Fixed Point */
            return -1; 
        } 
            
        //main function 
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        { 
            int arr[] = {99999999/*some very positive value*/, -10, -1, 0, 4/*note this 4*/, 10, 11, 30, 50, 100}; 
            int n = arr.length; 
            System.out.println("Fixed Point is " 
                       + binarySearch(arr, 1, n));         
        }  
    }
```

output:

```
Fixed Point is 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your binary search replacing mid with (mid+1).

```
class Main 
    { 
        static int binarySearch(int arr[], int low, int high) 
        { 
            if(high >= low) 
            {    
                /* low + (high - low)/2; */
                int mid = low+(high-low)/2;   
                if((mid+1) == arr[mid]) 
                    return mid+1; 
                if((mid+1) > arr[mid]) 
                    return binarySearch(arr, (mid + 1), high); 
                else
                    return binarySearch(arr, low, (mid -1)); 
            } 
            
            /* Return -1 if there is  
               no Fixed Point */
            return -1; 
        } 
            
        //main function 
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        { 
            int arr[] = {0,1,3,4}; 
            int n = arr.length; 
            System.out.println("Fixed Point is " 
                       + binarySearch(arr,0, n-1));         
        }  
    }
```

**Input:**

> arr = {0,1,3,4}

**Output:**

> Fixed Point is 3

Comment: it does not work for array {1,2,3,4}, in that case, it will return 2, instead of 1.

Comment: @dryre It's Binary Search, it will find the condition of satisfiability...